# tmux can't find running server when executed from bash script

Tags: bash, tmux

I have a simple bash script with many commands as below:

```
(cd /home/mc/ ;
echo msg-here ;
tmux send-keys -t mc "say xyz" ENTER ;
echo successful ;) > scripts/logs/$(date +%d-%m-%Y).txt
```

When executing the script, I get the result of `no server running on /tmp/tmux-0/default` in my terminal, despite the fact I can execute `tmux send-keys -t mc "say xyz" ENTER` from the terminal with no problems.

---

**Notes**

- I am running the script and the command from the same place (and both as the `mc` user).
- Output to log file doesn't show the error message, but instead looks as if everything worked.

Thanks

Comment: `/tmp/tmux-0/` suggest that your script is running under userid 0, since the default place tmux uses is constructed from the id.

Comment: You are only redirecting stdout to a logfile. Most Unix programs print errors on stderr. Instead of `>logfile` you need `>logfile 2>&1`. What's more, the `echo` commands are executed unconditionally, so they are misleading stating the operation was "successful". You would need something like `tmux ... && echo successful` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Attention:** This is only a workaround - however it seems to work flawlessly for my use-case.

**Method:** I created a new bash script `myscript-entry.sh` which runs the main script as the actual user.

Contents of script follow.

```
su -c "/home/mc/myscript.sh" - mc
```

Execute `sudo ./myscript-entry.sh` from the directory containing both scripts (or anywhere since the "entry" script uses absolute path) and the tmux commands should now be executed properly.